# Where does Laravel 4.2 store the user ID within the session data?

Tags: php, session, laravel, laravel-4, session-variables

I'm trying to wrap my head around how Laravel handles session data without digging too deeply into the code, due to time contraints.

It appears that the session ID ('laravel_session', by default) which is stored in a cookie is encrypted, because it is a different, much longer value than I get if I print the value of Session::getId()

So I'm assuming that Laravel is encrypting this value before dropping the cookie, and then decrypting the value to do the session data look-up every time session data is required.

So I guess my first question is:

**1. Why is the session ID obfuscated like this? I'm presuming that it is for security purposes?**

Secondly, I see no 'user_id' (or similarly worded) key in the actual session data once it has been pulled from disk. In fact, the only thing I see aside from the CSRF _token value is some entry like 'login_42e5d2c566bd0811218f0cf078b76bfd' = 1.

**2. What is this data responsible for?**

**3. Can someone please give me a brief overview of how Laravel associates the session data with a specific user ID?**

Answer (score -1):

Why are you digging into the session to get the `user ID`? You can have sessions without logging in - so `user ID` doesnt always mean something.

If you want the currently logged in user - then you should be using `Auth::user()->id`

Comment: thanks for your reply :) Yes, I'm aware sessions can exist without a logged-in user. That being said, when a user IS logged in, their session data is being associated with their record somehow and I'd like to know how it works. I'm trying to learn more about how Laravel works behind the scenes. If you can answer the questions I've asked I will select your answer. Thanks again for you reply.